# BreezeJS REST saveChanges

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, breeze

I've been pouring over BreezeJS documentation and stackoverflow posts looking for definitive information on using BreezeJS to interact with a REST tier (not .NET) that supports CRUD operations. I've read a number of posts that clearly communicates the philosophy behind the default behavior of saveChanges() which sends a collection of updated entities to the server. While creating server-side code to handle this may be possible it is likely that won't be our preferred path and yes, I do understand that there are transactional and state issues that decision would inflict on the client code.

In my searches on stackoverflow I've found a number of questions that are similar to mine, but those questions are all relatively old (at least for JavaScript libraries) - (ex. [Save changes to RESTful URLS with Breeze JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796102/save-changes-to-restful-urls-with-breeze-js)).

Some of those posts, including the one above, seem to indicate that work is/has been done to address the desire to do CRUD operations via normal REST operations.

Finally my questions: What is the current state of BreezeJS with regard to supporting RESTful CRUD operations? If I choose to manage the entity updates via a named save operation what kinds of hoops will I need to jump through to get Breeze to send those CRUD operations to my REST tier? What else am I missing in my summary above that will make CRUD operations from BreezeJS to a REST tier challenging?

Note: our JavaScript framework is Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do understand your question and your perspective. I haven't had time to document how to do this yet.

You'll find clues in the "breeze.ccjsActiveRecordDataServiceAdapter.js" in the **CC-JS Ruby** sample. That adapter is easy to [**examine in github**](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/ruby/CCJS-Ruby/client/app/services/breeze.ccjsActiveRecordDataServiceAdapter.js).And also in the "breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint" adapter which you can [**examine in github**](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js).

Both adapters target servers that want PUT/POST/DELETE to specific per-type endpoints (and do not understand "batch saves").

Intend to do a thorough presentation and sample for these "REST CRUD" scenarios "soon" ... but probably not before May.

Comment: Sorry, not yet. Just a matter of timing. The code is there. July or August seem a more likely time for example building. Unless you want to have a go and contribute :-)

Comment: I've got some stuff that "works" but I'm fairly new to using Breeze so I'm sure there are better ways than what I'm doing ;)

Comment: @BogdanVarlamov you may want to take a look at the breeze.labs.dataservice.abstractrest.js. We had an initial cut working based on the examples above, but switched to this implementation because it yielded much clearer code.